# ASP.NET Core 5.0 - catching string from text field as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<form class="form-inline" asp-controller="Search" asp-action="Index">
   <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

This moves us to the controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string query)
{
   //get data
   return View(data);
}
```

But obviously `query` is always empty, because I'm not sending it as parameter. Question is how to do it? It's easy when you have some model in view, but I don't know how to bind these two without model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with adding a name attribute to the input and set its value to the parameter name:

```
<input name="query" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: Flawless. Marking as solution once stackoverflow timers lets me.